# Solving trigonometric equations for the angle

Tags: trigonometry

Antenna applications have found me rough around the edges when it comes to my trigonometry. I need to solve equations in the following form:

$$\cos\theta\cos(2\theta) = 0.5$$

$$\cos^2(\theta)\cos^2(3\theta) = 0.5$$

I couldn't seem to find some formulas that would transform the product/sum of two functions into a single function so i can do a simple `arccos(0.5) =` . If there aren't just any formulas, i might understand how to do them with a solved example.

Comment: You can convert $\cos (n\theta)$ into a polynomial in $\cos \theta$ with degree $n$ - then solve the polynomial's roots which lie in $[-1,1]$ and then back convert to $\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos(2\theta)\equiv2\cos^2\theta-1$, so your first equation can be turned into
$$
\cos\theta(2\cos^2\theta-1)=0.5\ ,
$$
which can be turned into the cubic
$$
4\cos^3\theta-2\cos\theta-1=0\ ,
$$
So you'll have to go solve the cubic
$$
4x^3-2x-1=0
$$
before you can solve for $\theta$.

For your second equation you'll need to use
$$
\cos3\theta\equiv 4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks approachable now.